# How to set more strict compiling rules in VC when compile C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, metaprogramming, visual-c++-2008

guys,
I want VC has the same strict compile rules as GCC when it compiles the c++ template code. But I don't know how to set this in my VC9.0 (Visual Studio 2008).

For example,
the following code is not allowed in GCC.

`AutoPtr<RefCounted<Shape>> shape;`

since ">>" is not allowed here, and gcc requests to add at least one space between ">>" .

`AutoPtr<  RefCounted<Shape>   > shape;`

VC will not treat this as a error. From my understanding, VC has a more loose restriction on template code compiling.

How do I add more restriction in VC to make it be a same rules as GCC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. :( MSVC++ simply handles templates incorrectly, and you have to be careful.

---

Note that your particular example isn't actually an error in [C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b0x/info), so MSVC2010 would actually be right to accept it. (It's still wrong on lots of other things, though, but it's gotten a bit better.)

You might even "cheat" and enable C++0x for your gcc compile to allow it; just be sure not to accidentally use C++0x stuff MSVC2008 (or MSVC2010!) can't support.

Comment: If I want to write a portable code, I feel inconvenience since when I compile the code in gcc, it has many many errors where VC didn't treat it as error. My main editor is VC.

Comment: @giggle: I know exactly what you mean, I'm the same. It is just very unfortunate; turn it into a chance to quiz yourself on your template knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't really call it an error- C++0x has this restriction lifted, so I'd get used to it. More importantly, Visual Studio is perfectly happy to accept C++03-compliant brackets with a space between, so I'd just use that and forget about it. There's no way to change the fact that Visual Studio's parser is not as specified in the Standard and this is the least significant way in which it is non-conformant.

Comment: There's no way to make it totally compliant, but `/Za` helps.

Comment: And so does a higher warning level, /W4.

Answer (score 1):

I respectfully disagree with GMan's statement: "MSVC++ simply handles templates incorrectly". Instead, I would say that both MSVC and GCC handle templates incorrectly, each in its own way :)

To deal with compiler specifics it's worth to maintain a set of some compile-time test modules. Also, modern build systems such as bjam can be configured to run a brief unit test right after project's compilation. So all you will have to do is to build your project from time to time with gcc toolset (and/or on non-windows platform) to make sure everything works as expected.

PS. down-votes are not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [disabling Microsoft-specific extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx)?

Comment: MSVC's handling of templates is merely wrong, not an extension, unfortunately. (It fails on the most fundamental level: it doesn't do two-phase look-up.)

Comment: @GMan: True.  The question asks about "same rules as gcc", and that isn't possible, but the title mentions "more strict" and `/Za` IS more strict than `/Ze`.